# Match password efficiently in Spring Boot - JPA

Tags: json, spring-boot, jpa, passwords

I have `User` class like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
@Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
String eMail;
String passwordHash;
}
```

And I have data like this :

```
[{"userID":1,"passwordHash":"asdasd","email":"admin@admin.com"},
{"userID":2,"passwordHash":"12345","email":"admin1asdasd@admin.com"}]
```

I have two method , one - to get single user :

```
// Single item

@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
User one(@PathVariable Long id) {

    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}
```

Other method to retrieve all user :

```
// Aggregate root

@GetMapping("/user")
List<User> all() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

Now how can I match password ? What will be the efficient way ?

Comment: I would add a new method to the repository which does a select for the combination of email and password hash.

Comment: Match which password ? You mean inputting an unhashed password , find out all user 's password is the same as the input password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [this kind of an aproach](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt): in general, you should save hashed password in the database and check passwords using hashed values. Bcrypt is a good option for hashing and it can be easily integrated with Spring.

As explained in the link above you can define a password encoder service:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

//...
User user = new User();
user.setFirstName(accountDto.getFirstName());
user.setLastName(accountDto.getLastName());

user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));

user.setEmail(accountDto.getEmail());
user.setRole(new Role(Integer.valueOf(1), user));
repository.save(user);
```

where `accountDto` contains the password in clear-text.

Now you can expose a dedicated login method that compares hashed values, something along these lines:

```
void login(String username, char[] password) throws Exception {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user != null) {
        String encodedPassword = user.getPassword();
        if(passwordEncoder.matches(String.valueOf(password), encodedPassword)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("User cannot be authenticated");
}
```